# Get the ID of the selected value from a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, sqlconnection

```
    private void frmNSS5_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"workstation id = PC-PC; user id=sa;Password=sapassword; data source=pc-pc; persist security info=True; initial catalog=CleanPayrollTest2");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IsNull(ArEmpName,'') + ' ' + IsNull(ArFatherName,'') + ' ' + IsNull(ArLastName,'') as EmpName, ID as ID FROM [Emp] ", con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            this.cbEmpName.ValueMember = "ID".ToString();
            this.cbEmpName.DisplayMember = "EmpName";
            this.cbEmpName.DataSource = ds.Tables["EmpName"];
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if(dr[0].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    this.cbEmpName.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }

}
    private void comboEmpName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Emp ID:" + ' ' + this.cbEmpName.SelectedValue + ", " + "EmpName:" + ' ' + this.cbEmpName.SelectedItem   );
    }
```

I'm not getting the ID while selecting an employee, the messssage box just show me the name... Can someone tell me where's my fault? Thank you so much

Comment: what's `"ID".ToString()` ??? :D

Comment: You are selecting id and name but you are only adding the name in the `while`. Your `DataSet` and `DataTable` are also unused and `"ID".ToString()` is funny. You should also use the `using`-statement for the connection and the datareader to ensure that they get disposed(closed) also in case of exception.

Comment: sorry the Tostring thing has been added by fault..

Comment: Yes, now I can see what i'm coding.. Thank You so much

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it worked for you....

Comment: I need to add one thing, I don't want to show the ID in the combobox.. so if I add the ID in the while it's gona be shown in the combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After databinding the combobox you delete the binding by inserting the values using a datareader. Just remove this part:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    if(dr[0].ToString().Length > 0)
    {
        this.cbEmpName.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the code you should change the line that adds the item so it includes both the Value and the display data:

```
this.cbEmpName.Items.Add(
    new { EmpName = dr[0].ToString(), ID = dr[1].ToString()});
```

Comment: I'm gonna keep it because when i'm deleting it, i'm getting an empty combobox.. thank You so much

Comment: If you stick to the DataReader that is the way. If you opt for a dataadapter you can use the databinding.

Comment: What do You think it's better ?

Comment: It doesn't matter much in this case. The DataAdapter is primarily useful for updates, not for showing a lookuplist.

Comment: oh I see.. Sorry for bothering You in such questions, but if you have time could You tell me what to do if i don't want to set the ID in the Combobox, i just want to store the ID in a variable to use it later on..
Thx for the help

Comment: You need to put the ID in the ComboBox becuase you will need to get the ID later but if you set the DisplayMember property to EmpName you will not see it. That is what the property is for. If you don't do this you'll need to keep the ID with the Names somewhere. In that case I'd store the names and ID's in a DataTable (using a DataAdapter) and do a lookup of the Employee's name in the DataTable to find the matching ID. It can be done but I'd rather use DataBinding or the Display/ValueMember option as it is less work. If this doesn't answer your question, could you try to explain better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.cbEmpName.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString(),dr[4].ToString()));
```

Comment: Sorry for my question.. But what do you mean by the number 4 ?

Comment: I think it has to be 1.. I'm not sure

Comment: It should actually be 3, because ID is 4th column in your query and indexes in dr start from 0

Comment: Would You help me with one more thing?
I don't want to show in the combobox the ID, only the name.. How that could be done ?